# Command to know what was mounted in a folder

Tags: linux, console, backup, debian-jessie, bacula

I have a folder on my server that mounts volumes of a FreeNAS via the iSCSI protocol. I need to mount these same folders on another server but I can't figure out how they were mounted because the naming in FreeNAS and the folders are different.
 
Are there any commands I can use to see how they were assembled? Using the `df` command I have the following return:

```
/dev/sde       1008G  605G  352G  64% /mnt/folder1
/dev/sda       1008G  150G  808G  16% /mnt/folder2
/dev/sdf        4,0T  4,0T     0 100% /mnt/folder3
```

But this is not useful since I can't figure out which volumes these mounts are referencing.

I'm Using Debian GNU/Linux 8.9 (jessie) and FreeNAS 9.10.2.

Comment: Perhaps you could add details to your question. If the `df` output is from the backup server in question, it shows mounted folders on the right and physical storage devices on the left. You don't usually mount anything to a directory in a folder.

Comment: These folders are mounting volumes of a FreeNAS. I need to mount the same folders on another server but I can't figure out which FreeNAS volume they are mounting.

Comment: Again, it doesn't make sense. The folders are mounted on `/dev/sdX` - they are scsi devices (sd) - not volumes.

Comment: It actually uses the iSCSI protocol, which looks structurally like SCSI.

Comment: Ah I see. `iscsiadm` won't solve it for you?

Comment: Oh, that was really helpful. It was not as I imagined but I managed to get where I wanted with `iscsiadm`. Thank you very much wick.

Comment: no prob. I wasn't as expert to put a proper answer, but if you would upvote my every comment to this question i would appreciate your help in building my reputation score.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to approve comments, but if you respond with the solution you showed in the comments, I'll mark it as a solution =D

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments to the original question, `/dev/sdX` is simulated devices with iSCSI protocol. To manage those you would normally use `iscsiadm` command.